# Is it possible to make dynamically VStack in the HStack when screen width ends

Tags: swiftui

Basically, my requirement place array of string into `Text` horizontally but when screen width can not contain next `Text` I need to move it into next Line (I know it will be VStack then) as shown in the pic blow

[image]

is it possible in SwiftUI